# How to implement a logging macro with automatic newline in C++

Tags: c++, ostream

In the C++ library [glog](https://github.com/google/glog) (Google logging module) there is a nice interface where you can write

`LOG(INFO) << "abc " << my_var;`

and at runtime it prints something like `abc 5\n` at runtime (if my_var was 5) where it automatically terminated with a newline.

This is much superior to having to always terminate with `std::endl` as in

`std::cout << "abc " << my_var << std::endl;`

What is the simpliest way (code + macros) do I need to replicate this effect in my code?

Comment: Have a wrapper type (around the logging type) with implicit conversion and a dtor that adds the newline to the wrapped logger ?

Comment: That sounds promising @Borgleader. However implicit conversion is a feature of C++ I don't really understand that well. I will have to do some reading before I fully understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the idea is to return a temp wrapper object:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Log
{
    ~Log(void) { ::std::cout << ::std::endl; }
};

template<typename T> Log &&
operator <<(Log && wrap, T const & whatever)
{
    ::std::cout << whatever;
    return ::std::move(wrap);
}

int main()
{
    Log() << "whatever";
    Log() << "more";
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U9EngDOsa8EhioSs)

Note that the macro can be used here to execute conditional branching in the beginning of logging. That is skip logging if severity level is low.

```
#define LOG(level) \
    if(g_log_lelevel <= level) Log()
```

Comment: Very clever! Thanks!

Comment: @Borgleader I don't think implicit conversion is used here is it? I would still be interested in seeing usage of that C++ feature if you still want to post your answer

Comment: @Mark I actually changed my mind about the conversion operator, overloading `operator<<` made more sense, so as a result [my code sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3350a3f49085dd5a) is almost identical to VTT